# Cannot find Sierra .app file for bootable os

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I am trying to install Sierra to my Macbook Pro but I cannot find an installer .app file to make a bootable os. How and where to download it?

Comment: You're too late. High Sierra is out, Sierra is gone from the App Store.

Comment: I know that. I somehow need the app installer.

Comment: Can't verify if this link still works, but this used to be it: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?mt=12

Comment: @slhck ...nope - it's gone. Gone from everybody's purchased list too.

Comment: This was a good investigation of what happened - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286311/macos-sierra-doesnt-appear-in-my-purchased-list-within-the-mac-app-store/286312#286312

Answer (score 0):

[This apple page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?ls=1&mt=12)

takes one to an App Store page where Sierra can be downloaded. I just tried the page and Sierra began to download. However, the cited page (same URL as slhck posted above) might offer Sierra to my Mac because it runs Sierra.